# Why do I get ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `isebook' for nil:NilClass on Heroku but not locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails 4 app running SQLite locally and PostgreSQL on Heroku.

I have a products class, which has a boolean column "isebook" that is set to either true or false in a form on products/new.html.erb.

```
<%= form_for(@product, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
      <% if @product.errors.any? %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

          <h3><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h3>

          <ul>
          <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control"  %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :link %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :link, class: "form-control"  %>
        <p style="font-size:12px; margin-top:2px;"><i>(Begin link with http:// or https://)</i></p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :description %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control"  %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label "Product is an Ebook?" %> <br />
        <%= f.check_box :isebook %> <br />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :image, 'Product Image'  %><br>
        <%= f.file_field :image, class: "form-control"  %>

      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Create Product", class: "btn btn-primary"  %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

In the controller, this field is being required:

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :isebook, :image)
end
```

The entire code for the controller method:

```
def new

# Only make new product if user has remaining products

@product = Product.new

if current_user.prodused < current_user.prodlimit
  respond_with(@product)
else
  redirect_to user_path(current_user.id), error: "You've reached your product limit. Upgrade your account to add more products."
end

end
```

This is the product model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

 validates :name, :description, presence:true
 validates :link, :format => URI::regexp(%w(http https))

 belongs_to :user

 has_attached_file :image, :styles => {:medium => "300x300", :thumb => "200x200"}, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.jpg"

end
```

This works correctly locally, when a new product is created the isebook field is assigned true or false based on if the checkbox is selected or not.

I'm now attempting to test on Heroku, I cleared the entire production database and ran all the migration files to clear all existing products. I then created an account successfully, when attempting to render products/new.html.erb I get the error **ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `isebook' for nil:NilClas**

Comment: Post the code of the entire form, as well as the corresponding controller action

Comment: Edited to add entire form code, and the corresponding controller action.

Comment: From the stack trace can you figure out which line is causing the issue? The code seems fine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with stack trace, but when I comment out the div element with the checkbox that sets the isebook field the error no longer occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cleared the entire production database and ran all the migration files to clear all existing products. I then created an account successfully

Are there any products?

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `isebook' for nil:NilClas
```

This error means you've called the method `isebook` on `nil`, likely meaning you tried to load one or all products, but in your case they don't exist, so calling the method on `nil` (nothing) throws an error.